# Get Microsoft Teams Presence status in custom app

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, custom-application

I am installed custom app in Microsoft Teams. In custom app i want to get/change the user presence status by using Javascript/C#.net. I followed below way but here we need to pass authProvider. Instead of authProvider, get the user presence why because my custom app already installed in the microsoft Teams why again i need to pass the authProvider Details.

[image: In Microsoft Graph API call Required Azure App ClientID.]

In C#.net side followed below way.[image]

Please provide the solution to get the user presence. or provide other solutions to do this.

Comment: Hi @Saiprasad,

We are unable to reproduce the issue, could you please let us know the error code.

Answer (score 1):

For any graph api to access and to provide user details such as presence of an user, Auth provider is mandatory as it secures the details through an access token.

So Auth provider is necessary irrespective of the custom app uploaded in Teams.